# Rogue Alternate Class Features: Spell Reflection

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, rogue

On PHB II, Spell reflection from Complete Mage is proposed as an alternative class feature for rogue's evasion. The question is about the use of the actual feature. It says:

> You gain the supernatural ability to reflect magical attacks back on
>   their caster. If an enemy misses with a spell or spell-like ability
>   **aimed** at you you can use an immediate action to redirect the effect back at its original caster.

Emphasis mine. The book continues saying:

> This effect only applies to spells and spell-like abilities that require an attack roll. Other spells and spell-like abilities that affect a target aren't subject to spell reflection.

So I guess my question is: What exactly counts as aimed? Should this effect count against spells that use melee touch attacks as well?(For example inflict wounds, etc). Because what I believe the creators had in mind would be to replace the benefits of evasion (reflex vs effect) with a defense against rays for example.

Comment: “On PHB II...” *and* “from Complete Mage”? Spell reflection is in *Complete Mage*, and as far as I can tell *Player’s Handbook II* has nothing to do with it, but I wanted to ask for clarification rather than edit it out myself in case I am misunderstanding your meaning?

Comment: @KRyan On PHB II it is proposed as an alternative class feature instead of evasion for the rogue. And the complete description that the PHB II gives is "replace evasion with Spell reflection from complete mage". PHB II proposes the class feature which is described in Complete Mage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The effect applies only to spells and spell-like abilities that require an attack roll.

They could have said *ranged attack roll* if that is what they meant; that is the standard phrasing for this kind of thing, and a phrase they well know how to use. The fact that they didn’t strongly suggests that they didn’t mean to.

At any rate, nothing anywhere in the description of the spell reflection alternate class feature indicates that it is restricted to ranged attacks. Using a ranged attack as the example, or in the illustration, doesn’t mean that it only works on these. And “aiming” is not really unique to ranged attacks, and in any event is simply not the standard way that Wizards of the Coast used to indicate ranged attacks. Again, that would be using *ranged attack roll* in the above-quoted rules.

So as-written, spell reflection applies to all spells and spell-like abilities with any kind of attack roll, melee or ranged. And there is no real evidence to suggest that this was anything but intentional. Considering the fluff of melee touch attacks and how easily they are discharged, it does not seem entirely unreasonable that a martial artist could shove your hand into your other arm, your leg, whatever, and subject you to the discharge. And ultimately, this is a rather niche ability that really does not need to become *more* so.

Comment: I know there are a few spells that specify that casting them *includes* making a melee attack roll, but does the generic touch attack spell — *shocking grasp*, say — , technically, "require an attack roll"? That is, *touching the foe* requires an attack roll, but *casting the spell* doesn't require an attack roll yet the casting *itself* isn't aimed *per se*. Is that a distinction worth noting, or am I—as is my wont—simply overreading?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think you are overreading, by a considerable margin in this case.

Comment: So would you likewise rule that the special ability spell reflection functions against Ali the Boxing Magician's spell when he opts to use an unarmed strike to deliver an appropriate touch spell?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yup, I would, though I might let Ali avoid it if he missed the rogue’s regular AC but not touch AC.

Comment: Wow. That's complicated. Is such a mechanic endorsed elsewhere by the rules? Anyway, it sounds like the answer should maybe address this semi-corner case, but—as always—your call.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh no, that last bit is entirely my fabrication, just seems fair to me.